# How to make JSF setting null values into a List

Tags: jsf

Why JSF does not set null values back to a list (or array)?

An example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("testMB")
@Scope("view")
public class TestMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2463416120592801345L;

    private List<Double> doublesList;

    private List<Integer> integersList;

    private Double d = 123.456;

    private Integer i = 987;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setDoublesList(new ArrayList<Double>());
        setIntegersList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            getDoublesList().add(i + 0.123);
            getIntegersList().add(i);
        }
    }

    public List<Double> getDoublesList() {
        return doublesList;
    }

    public void setDoublesList(List<Double> doublesList) {
        this.doublesList = doublesList;
    }

    public List<Integer> getIntegersList() {
        return integersList;
    }

    public void setIntegersList(List<Integer> integersList) {
        this.integersList = integersList;
    }

    public Double getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(Double d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public Integer getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(getDoublesList());
        System.out.println(getIntegersList());
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

And the view...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">

            <p:fieldset legend="Doubles List">
                <ui:repeat varStatus="vs1" value="#{testMB.doublesList}">
                    #{v.index}
                    <p:inputText value="#{testMB.doublesList[vs1.index]}">
                        <f:convertNumber />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <br />
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:fieldset>

            <p:fieldset legend="Integers List">
                <ui:repeat varStatus="vs2" value="#{testMB.integersList}">
                    <p:inputText value="#{testMB.integersList[vs2.index]}">
                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <br />
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:fieldset>


            Double: 
            <p:inputText value="#{testMB.d}">
                <f:convertNumber />
            </p:inputText>
            <br />
            <br />

            Integer:
            <p:inputText value="#{testMB.i}">
                <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
            </p:inputText>

            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{testMB.doSomething}" update="form" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</f:view>

</html>
```

If a field of the list is set to an empty string, then the List is not updated with a null value, like it would be expected. It just remains the same value as it was before.

In web.xml I have:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But if I set the value of `testMB.d` or `testMB.i` input texts to an empty string, then it's properly set to null at the managed bean.

So, what´s the problem with JSF, lists and null values? How to implement this correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{testMB.doSomething}" update="form" />
```

I think the actionListener won't change the variable's values.

Comment: Thanks, but it happens that it does. If I change any values to something diferent than an empty string, it updates the value on the list. The thing is that only with the empty values that the list ignores the update.

Comment: Ah Ok. Now I understand you!

Comment: I did it already. But I used p:datalist instead ui:repeat and worked fine to me:

<p:dataList  var="vs2" value="#{testMB.integersList}">
    <p:inputText value="#{vs2.i}">
        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
    </p:inputText>
     <br />
</p:dataList>

Comment: Try with p:dataList too. Here it doesn´t update any value even if it's diferent than an empty string. But anyway, what´s this #{vs2.i} ? Why ".i" ? Here it gives me: `Property 'i' not found on type java.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: Each interation I get from testMB.integersList an object in vs2... Sorry it is only vs2, man.

Comment: Gaspar, which version of JSF are you using? And your Container, is Tomcat 7x?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.0 and my Container is Weblogic 11G. You know your list is made by Integer and Double, right!? I used it with p:datalist and added dynamically input filds to the view here. 
Take a look here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

JSF upgrading. From `2.1.10` to `2.2.0`.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>            
</dependency>
```